# Robust Regression in MATLAB's robustfit: what is the optimal weight function to tackle heteroskedasticity?

Tags: regression, least-squares, matlab, heteroscedasticity, robust

I'm currently performing a linear regression analysis and encountered a fair amount of heteroskedasticity. Increases in predicted values go along with *decreases* in residual variance. Otherwise, the residual distribution seems normal and shows no outliers.
I'm using matlab's `fitlm` for regression analysis and there are `RobustOpts`, which provide robust regression through the [`robustfit`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/robustfit.html) function. As far as I understand, `robustfit` is based on the [iteratively reweighted least squares method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares). My problem: `robustfit` offers an [array of weight functions](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/robustfit.html):

> 'andrews'   w = (abs(r) < pi) .* sin(r) ./ r
>
> 'bisquare'   w = (abs(r)<1) .* (1 - r.^2).^2
>
> 'cauchy'   w = 1 ./ (1 + r.^2)
>
> 'fair'  w = 1 ./ (1 + abs(r))
>
> 'huber'  w = 1 ./ max(1, abs(r))
>
> 'logistic'  w = tanh(r) ./ r
>
> 'talwar'  w = 1 * (abs(r)<1)
>
> 'welsch'  w = exp(-(r.^2))

Which of these weight functions is optimal or "best practice" to safeguard against homoskedasticity?